# Can't launch new line on Git Bash (Windows)

Tags: bash, git

I've just started learning how to use command lines (in this case, with Git Bash on Windows).

But I have a problem in which I'm not able to launch a new command line after opening a file in a given subdirectory from the Desktop.

However, as seen in the image, that won't happen if I open the same file from Desktop itself.

Also, if that's relevant, in the latter situation, if I close Git Bash, no notification will pop up, but in the scenario where I can't launch a new command file, the pop-up below will appear.
It doesn't matter how long I wait or if I type Renan@aph etc, the CDI just won't let me launch a new line and I have to restart it.

Any help will be immensely appreciated, thank you.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYbqt.png]

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: @shellter: this is a tool commonly used by developers and is on topic here.

Comment: Has any of the answers helped you? Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the working answer or use comments or editing to clarify your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling start from `C:\path\to\git\latest\usr\bin` instead of the [Windows START command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

If you are using a bash session, you won't be able to use Windows START, because it will be overshadowed by the one provided by Git.

Answer (score 0):

The last command you entered is still running. To run a command in the background so you can enter other commands while it’s running, you have to append `&` to your command, i.e.

```
start moon.jpg &
```

More information on background shell jobs can be found at https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job/